# Do a dynamic option dropdown in vue js based on a trips capacity number

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

A user has a trip, and each trip has a capacity. So one trip can have a capacity of 1 person, or 6 people. I made a component in Vue JS, and in it, I have a dropdown. I want to loop through that dropdown and show the number of people that are going to come along with the trip so I can calculate the total trip price.

So if the trip capacity is 4 people, I want to only show 4 options, 1 - 4.

This is how my component looks like:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label><small>Select amount of people going on this trip</small></label>   
        <select class="form-control" name="people">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            // ...... I want this to be dynamic with the trip number capacity
        </select>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default{
        props: ['trip'],
        methods() {

        },
        data() {
            return {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And this is what it returns, I will just show the trip capacity:

[image]

In this case, the "people" object (people is trip capacity) is 4. So I want to only show 4 option values.

How Would I do the for loop in the option area in Vue JS and set the number of option's to = the trip capacity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [range](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Range-v-for) `v-for`.

```
<select class="form-control" name="people">
  <option v-for="n in trip.people" :value="n">{{n}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: That was simple, thanks! Also, it starts the count at 0. So adding {{n + 1}} will start count at 1.

Comment: @David Do you mean yours starts at zero? This appears to start at one. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/jwXJzM

Comment: Yes, I forgot that the default starting option for capacity is 0.

Comment: @david understood :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to only show 4 options, 1 - 4 when you have 6 data,

your html

```
<select class="form-control" name="people">
  <option v-for="people in onlyDisplay" :value="people">{{people}}</option>
</select>
```

your computed

```
//my data
const people=["Benjamin", "Nathan", "Bane","Natasha", "X", "Y"]
computed: {
  onlyDisplay(){ 
    return people.slice(0,3)
  }
}
```